# How to get list of custom annotations of a class?

Tags: java

My goal is to get list of custom annotations of a class.

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {
  @Autowired
  private final IntegerService integerService;

  @Autowired
  private final BooleanService booleanService;

  public HelloController(IntegerService integerService, BooleanService booleanService) {
    this.integerService = integerService;
    this.booleanService = booleanService;
  }

  @GetMapping
  public String getHello() {
    return String.format("Hello %d %b", integerService.getRandomInt(), booleanService.getRandomBoolean());
  }
}
```

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface RestController {
}
```

What I have done:

1. do `Class.forName`

```
        Class<?> clazz = null;
        try {
          clazz = Class.forName("looslycoupled.controller.HelloController");
//          clazz = Class.forName(String.format("%s.%s", packageName, resource.substring(0, resource.lastIndexOf("."))));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        assert clazz != null;
        Annotation[] annotations = clazz.getDeclaredAnnotations();
        System.out.println(clazz.isAnnotationPresent(RestController.class));
        for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
          System.out.println(annotation.getClass());
        }
```

My expected result: `clazz.getDeclaredAnnotations()` return `[interface looslycoupled.framework.annotation.RestController]`

My actual result: it return `[class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1]`.

2. I tried to call `clazz.isAnnotationPresent(RestController.class)`. It return `true`. So, I am not sure why `clazz.getDeclaredAnnotations()` return different result.

EDIT:

`annotation.annotationType()` does the job.

Comment: You edited question with self-answer. Self-answering is generally welcome in SO, however you should post it as an answer and accept it. It helps other to see that question is marked as solved.

Answer (score 0):

`annotation.annotationType()` does the job.